# JS not working after Checkbox if else condition for breaking sentences into span letter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i am breaking sentences into `<span class="word">` and then `<span class='letter'>` through this simple js and its working demo:

```html
<h1 id="text">
this is demo text that is breaking word into span letter
</h1>

<style>
.word {border: 1px solid red;}
.letter {border: 1px solid lightblue;}
</style>

<script>
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('#text');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/(\S*)/g, m => {
  return `<span class="word">` +
    m.replace(/(-|)?\S(-|@)?/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>") +
    `</span>`;
});

</script>
```

But now i want that sentences should be break into `<span class="word">` and then `<span class='letter'>` only if when Checkbox is active else this is not should be break.

i tried these code but it's not working, what mistake am making can i know plz stackoverflow community.

```
<label for="myCheck">Checkbox:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">

<h1 id="text" >Checkbox is CHECKED!</h1>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var textWrapper = document.querySelector('#text');
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/(\S*)/g, m => {
  return `<span class="word">` +
    m.replace(/(-|)?\S(-|@)?/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>") +
    `</span>`;
});
  } else {
     textWrapper.style.display = "block";
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:-

```js
textWrapper.style.display = "block";
```

doesn't undo the changes caused by

```js
 textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/(\S*)/g, m => {
  return `<span class="word">` +
    m.replace(/(-|)?\S(-|@)?/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>") +
    `</span>
```

because `display: block;` doesn't negate css. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).

You should use a similar replace to undo the changes.

A possible solution to your problem is:-

```html
<style>
.word {border: 1px solid red;}
.letter {border: 1px solid lightblue;}
</style>

<label for="myCheck">Checkbox:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">

<h1 id="text" >Checkbox is CHECKED!</h1>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var textWrapper = document.querySelector('#text');
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/(\S*)/g, m => {
  return `<span class="word">` +
    m.replace(/(-|)?\S(-|@)?/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>") +
    `</span>`;
});
  } else {
     textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
  }
}
</script>
```

Note that here

```js
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
```

strips `textContent` of any html tags.

Answer (score 1):

Hold your original text on some variable and based upon your check box checked replace your text with the original text.

```js
var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('#text');
var orginalText = document.getElementById("text").textContent;

function myFunction(obj) {

  if (checkBox.checked == true) {

    textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/(\S*)/g, m => {
      return `<span class="word">` +
        m.replace(/(-|)?\S(-|@)?/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>") +
        `</span>`;
    });
  } else {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = orginalText;
  }
}
```

```css
.word {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.letter {
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<label for="myCheck">Checkbox:</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction(this)">

<h1 id="text">Checkbox is CHECKED!</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

why you cant try this
This is not an optimal solution , but looks like working for your needs

```
    function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var textWrapper = document.querySelector('#text');
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/(\S*)/g, m => {
  return `<span class="word">` +
    m.replace(/(-|)?\S(-|@)?/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>") +
    `</span>`;
});
  } else {
   var oldText = `<h1 id="text">Checkbox is CHECKED!</h1>`
     textWrapper.innerHTML = ""
     textWrapper.innerHTML = oldText
  }
}
```